# Django i18n - same string used as ugettext and ugettext_lazy

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n

I am in the process of translating a site to multiple languages.

When I try to translate our labels for certain classes, I run into some problems because these label-classes are used in both views and models/forms (the very place Django says the distinction between ugettext and ugettext_lazy is)

The problem is: I would rather not write every label-class function twice and translate the labels with ugettext & ugettext_lazy respectively. Can this be done in a better way?

My main concern is that if the same strings exists two places, there is double the maintenance in the future, can the strings only exists one place?

Example of vanilla lable-class:

```
class CurrencyChoice(object):
    GBP = 10
    USD = 20
    EUR = 30

    def labels():
        return (
        CurrencyChoice.GBP, u'Great Britain Pound'
        CurrencyChoice.USD, u'USA Dollar'
        CurrencyChoice.EUR, u'Euro'
        )
```

Example of i18n solution I would like to avoid:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy, ugettext

class CurrencyChoice(object):
    GBP = 10
    USD = 20
    EUR = 30

    def labels():
        return (
        (CurrencyChoice.GBP, ugettext(u'Great Britain Pound')),
        (CurrencyChoice.USD, ugettext(u'USA Dollar')),
        (CurrencyChoice.EUR, ugettext(u'Euro')),
        )

    def labels_lazy():
        return (
        (CurrencyChoice.GBP, ugettext_lazy(u'Great Britain Pound')),
        (CurrencyChoice.USD, ugettext_lazy(u'USA Dollar')),
        (CurrencyChoice.EUR, ugettext_lazy(u'Euro')),
        )
```